# Mouse over and off XHTML/HTML5

Tags: html, animation, xhtml

I am looking at creating a simple animation in where if you move the mouse open the button opens and you see a word, if you move off of it, the button closes.

What I want though is a reverse order of it opening, so when the mouse moves from the button it slowly closes instead of snapping shut, just like how it opened.

Is there a way to make this possible using only XHTML or HTML5?

Comment: What do you mean the button slowly closes?

Comment: This is not a HTML5 stuff, you should investigate about CSS3 animations or JS animations.

Comment: You may be able to do this with CSS...depends on what "opens" means.

Comment: @Andy Button is closed, move the mouse over the button, and animation starts up, link is viable, move the mouse away, and the button closes with a reverse animation, and the link is no longer viable. Hope this helps.

Comment: @Skatox I'm still learning HTML 5 and CSS 3, I know XHTML and CSS, so I've yet to get into that realm. So pardon that I don't know that yet.

Comment: @Dan I have the generic open and close animation using a mouse over condition, I was wondering if there was something else, that's all.

Comment: @MattRidge You can't do it purely with html, you can do it with CSS, just style the button to look greyed out, then add a `:hover` style with a css transition and all will be well :)

Comment: @MattRidge not problem, just saying because maybe you won't find how to do it by looking for html5

Answer (score 4):

If I understood your request right, this is what you want:

```
<div id="button">
    <span>This is your Text</span>

</div>

<style>
    #button{
        height: 20px;
        width: 100px;
        background-color: blue;
        color: white;
        transition: height 0.25s linear 0.25s;
    }

    #button span{
        opacity: 0;
        transition: opacity 0.1s linear;
    }

    #button:hover{
        height: 50px;
        transition: height 0.25s linear;
    }

    #button:hover span{
        opacity: 1;
        transition: opacity 0.1s linear 0.25s;
    }
</style>
```

This snippet creates a button 100x20px and on hover (when you move with your mouse over) it gets bigger and the text gets shown.